# Присвоение элементам class с помощью js, работа с innerHTML и получение данных из адресной строки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Если в адресной строке нет ничего после знака "?" - то должен присваиваться определенный `class` некоторым элементам и вноситься изменения в элемент с `class="error"`, чего не происходит. В каком месте я ошибся? Вроде все правильно сделал.

Код:

Html:

```
<body>
        <div class="error"></div>
        <p class="llogin" id="llogin">Ваш логин: <p></p><p>
        <p class="mail" id="mail">Ваш Mail: <p></p></p>
        <p class="phone" id="phone">Ваш телефон: <p></p></p>
        <form>
            <input placeholder="Изменить логин" class="login" name="login" id="login">
            <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Сменить пароль" name="password" id="password">
            <input type="repass" class="repass" placeholder="Повторите пароль" name="repassword" id="repass">
            <input placeholder="Изменить mail или телефон" class="binding" name="binding" id="binding">
        </form>
        <button class="button" id="button">Изменить данные</button>
    </body>
```

Js:

```
 var str = window.location.search.replace( '?', '');
        var ver;
        if(str = ""){
            document.querySelector("#llogin").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#mail").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#phone").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#password").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#repass").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#binding").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#button").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector(".error").innerHTML = "Произошла неизвестная ошибка";
        }else{
```

Comment: Только что выяснил, что ошибка где-то в условии. Как ее исправить и что за ошибка?

Comment: `=` -----> `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**var str = location.search.substring(1);**

```
https://some.url?then=some&query=string

location.search.substring(1) = then=some&query=string  

if(str = ""){ // str присвоили ""
```